# Element not getting displayed on dynamic dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my code, basically, on click of button, I want to call this method addpoc() which creates a block of input boxes and a dropdown. And on the selection of dropdown option personal/workmail an input box should appear.
It is happening for the first time where I have not creating any block dynamically but after that I can see the dropdown but input box is not coming as per the selected option in the dropdown. And also for some reason this undefined is coming as well.

```js
function addpoc() {
  let el;
  el += '<div class="clearfix"><div class="name"><label for="fname">First name:</label><br><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ricky"></div><div class="name"><label for="lname">Last name:</label><br><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ju"></div></div><div class="parent" style="width: 100%;"><div id="one"><select id="contact method" onchange="showMail()"><option value="workmail" selected>Work email </option><option value="personalmail">Personal Email</option></select></div><div id="two" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Work email"></div><div id="three" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Personal email"></div></div>'

  $('#addelement').append(el);
}

function showMail() {
  let selecteop = document.getElementById("contact method");
  if (selecteop.value == "workmail") {

    $("#two").show();
    $("#three").hide();
  } else {
    $("#three").show();
    $("#two").hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="name">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ricky">
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ju">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="width: 100%;">
  <div id="one">
    <select id="contact method" onchange="showMail()">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Preferred contact method</option>
    
      <option value="workmail">Work email </option>
      <option value="personalmail">Personal Email</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="two" style="display: none;">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Work email">
  </div>
  <div id="three" style="display: none;">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Personal email">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="addelement"></div>
  <button id="addbtn" onclick="addpoc()">Add another point of contact</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function **showMail** should take an input that indicates which **SELECT** element is changed. So the first thing is to switch to `onchange="showMail(this)"` to pass the changed element to the function. Next you need to target the closest **TWO** and **THREE** elements. Targeting an id with # sign will always select the first occurance in the document so you need to give those divs a class name e.g. `.two` and `.three` then using jquery selectors, target to the desired one. I used `.closest(".parent").find(".two")` but you may find another logic to to find the nearest divs.

**about undefinded:** Variables defined with let must be Declared before use even with an empty value.

```js
function addpoc() {
  let el='';
  el += '<br><div class="clearfix"><div class="name"><label for="fname">First name:</label><br><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Ricky"></div><div class="name"><label for="lname">Last name:</label><br><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ju"></div></div><div class="parent" style="width: 100%;"><div id="one"><select id="contact method" onchange="showMail(this)"><option disabled selected>Prefered contact method</option><option value="workmail">Work email </option><option value="personalmail">Personal Email</option></select></div><div class="two" id="two" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Work email"></div><div class="three" id="three" style="display: none;"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Personal email"></div></div><br>'

  $('#addelement').append(el);
}

//Creating first block instead of repeating codes in html
addpoc();

function showMail(selecteop) {
  if (selecteop.value == "workmail") {
    $(selecteop).closest(".parent").find(".two").show();
    $(selecteop).closest(".parent").find(".three").hide();
  } else {
    $(selecteop).closest(".parent").find(".three").show();
    $(selecteop).closest(".parent").find(".two").hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="addelement"></div>
  <button id="addbtn" onclick="addpoc()">Add another point of contact</button>
</div>
```